# Uneven FPS on iOS despite consistent, low CPU and GPU load

Tags: ios, profiler, frame-rate

Profiling our game on an iPad Pro, XCode tells me:

- GPU time is 4ms
- CPU time spent feeding the GPU is ~60% of the CPU load

If I interact with the app (swiping to spin a static game view around) CPU usage is around 30%, but very spiky. If I don't interact, CPU usage surges toward 100%, presumably because the device throttles down when the screen isn't being touched. FPS drops from 60 to 40/30.

So, first question: Is there any way to force or hint that the device should not do this? The game needs to run smoothly even when the user is not touching the screen.

Secondly, the CPU usage when I *am* touching the screen is very, very spiky, despite the fact that nothing in the scene is changing. Exactly the same geometry is being marshaled and presented every frame, and no other work is being done (the game is essentially paused).

The time profiler (Instruments) is no help at all. Comparing the 'high usage' spikes with the 'low usage' periods, there are no significant differences in the proportion of CPU time spent in any part of the app, despite those frames allegedly taking 2-3 times as long to complete. Again, it looks as though CPU throttling is to blame, but it's very choppy and uneven. Sometimes we get 60fps, then it will drop to 40 or 30 for no evident reason, and with nothing extra showing up in the profiler.

I'd love some kind of call chart like the one Android Studio provides, to get some clock-time sense of what's going on, but I can't find one (just a million results for making pretty charts on a Mac). So, second question: is there some sort of plugin I can use to take the time profiling data and view it as a clock-time call chart?

Thanks.

Comment: Just an FYI, but this seems to be the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727578/ios-11-cpu-throttling-and-idle-timer